# SAS sequence number for an ID

Tags: sas

I have a data set like this:

```
ID_no   |  Medication_type
1       |    type_1
1       |    type_2
2       |    type_1
3       |    type_2
3       |    type_3
3       |    type_4
```

I want to transpose it into a set of

```
ID_NO | Medication 1 | Medication2 | Medication 3
1     | type_1       | type 2      | 
2     | Type_1       |             | 
3     | Type_2       | Type_3      | Type_4
```

To do this I need to do a proc transpose but I think I need a sequence number like this to get there:

```
ID_no |  Medication_type | Seq_NO
1     |  type_1          | 1
1     |  type_2          | 2
2     |  type_1          | 1
3     |  type_2          | 1
3     |  type_3          | 2
3     |  type_4          | 3
```

But unfortunately I'm having trouble making it in sas. I'm trying like this:

```
data want;
  set have;
  by ID_no;
  if first.ID_no then do;
    seq_no = 1;
    seq_no + 1;
  end;
run;
```

But it counts all the way up and I'm at a loss as to why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have a variable to use for grouping, you do not need another variable.

```
proc transpose data=have out=want prefix=medication_ ;
  by id_no;
  var medication_type;
run;
```

As to your attempt to create a SEQ_NO variable, you need to move the sum statement out of the IF block so that it runs for every observation. Something like this.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by ID_no ;
  if first.ID_no then seq_no=0;
  seq_no+1;
run;
```